# How to add cart icon react native action bar?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using `react-native-action-bar` for my app header and here is I need to add cart icon... I tried everything in right but can't get any solution for adding cart icon with counted items... if anyone has an idea for the same please let me know.

I used `rightIcons` but there are limited icons and the cart icon is missing also I need to add cart count with the icon.

```
<ActionBar
  containerStyle={{height:60}}
  backgroundColor={'#d7b655'}
  title={'Home'}
  titleStyle={styles.pageTitle}
  leftIconName={'menu'}
  onLeftPress={() =>           
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
  }
  rightIcons={[
      {
          name: 'cart',
          badge: '1',
          onPress: () => console.log('cart !'),
      },
  ]}
  rightIconImageStyle={{tintColor: 'green'}}
  rightIconContainerStyle={{Top:200}}
/>
```

It should show a cart icon with a count of total items with a dynamic count result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `react-native-action-bar` doesn't support a `cart` icon. The only predefined icons are: back, flag, loading, location, menu, phone, plus, start and  star-outline. Check out [here](https://github.com/Osedea/react-native-action-bar#predefined-icons).

Also, the library doesn't support [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons).

In your case I recommend you to use the [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/header.html) **Header** component:

```
<Header
  centerComponent={{ text: 'Home', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
  rightComponent={{ icon: 'shopping_cart', color: '#fff' }}
/>
```

To add a badge to your Icon, you can use the [badge component](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/badge.html):

```
import { Badge, Icon, withBadge } from 'react-native-elements'
...
const BadgedIcon = withBadge(1)(Icon);
```

In a combination, it will look like this:

```
<Header
    centerComponent={{ text: 'Home', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
    rightComponent={<BadgedIcon type="material" name="shopping_cart" />}
/>
```